# Python text file modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, text-files

I am trying to write a Python parser for modifying text inside the square brackets 
e.g. if the text file contains

```
    Original File contents : [ city is beautiful]
    Modified File contents : [ The city is beautiful]

    Original File contents : [ 123,456]
    Modified File contents : [ <mystring>,123,456]

    : [<oldtext>] should become : [<newtag>,<oldtext>]
```

Comment: You will probably get answers around splitting the string `'[ city is beautiful ]'` if that is all you show. Probably best to show a little more surrounding context so that potential answerers understand what kind of text needs to be matched vs. what is to be skipped.

Comment: Hi Paul, All I am interested in is playing around square brackets opening  "[" and closing "]". I want to modify the contents appearing between [ and ].

Comment: What is the criteria for matching "_city is beautiful_" and prepending it with "The"? Is it in its own line? Are you looking for a parser that basically prepends "The" to ALL text inside `[ ] `? Why "The"? If there is a line in the file that contains "[123]" should be replaced with "[The 123]"? These are the kinds of context you need to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) modules.

- [`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will be used for in-place file editing
- [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [`match.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will be used for capturing the text inside the brackets

Here's the code (I've placed the comments inline):

```
def modify_text_inside_brackets(file_name, tag):
    with fileinput.input(files=(file_name), inplace=True) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            # split the line into groups
            matches = re.match(r"(.*)(\[.*\])(.*)", line)
            if matches:
                # get the text inside the brackets
                #   group(0): the entire matching line
                #   group(1): everything before the opening [
                #   group(2): [ .. ]
                #   group(3): everything after the closing ]
                text_inside_brackets = matches.group(2)[1:-1]
                # create a new [..] string with the prepended tag
                modified_text = "[{},{}]".format(tag, text_inside_brackets.strip())
                # replace the original [..] with the modified [..]
                modified_line = line.replace(matches.group(2), modified_text)
                # print out the modified line to the file
                print(modified_line, end="")
            else:
                print(line, end="")


modify_text_inside_brackets("input.txt", "TAG")
```

Given this "input.txt":

```
[ 123,456]
[ city is beautiful]
This text has no brackets and should be unchanged.
It can also [ handle lines with inline] brackets.
```

The code will modify it like this:

```
[TAG,123,456]
[TAG,city is beautiful]
This text has no brackets and should be unchanged.
It can also [TAG,handle lines with inline] brackets.
```

Notes:

- `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True` redirects the `print` output to the file
- It's a unclear what `<mystring>` and `<newtag>` is from your question, so I just used `TAG`.
- Modify `"[{},{}]".format(tag, text_inside_brackets.strip())` based on the output format you need. For example, in your question, the spaces after `[` and before `]` are imbalanced and inconsistent in your examples, so add or [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) spaces as needed.
- You can check/test the regex itself from [this demo](https://regexr.com/3oqmn).
- I passed `end=""` to `print` because by default `print` adds a newline.